Bibtex no longer finds .bib files using TeXLive2024 after upgrading MacOS to Sequoia 15.0.1
Just upgraded two Macs to MacOS Sequoia 15.0.1. When I bibtex (using TexLive 2024 setup via aquamacs) I get a message that my bib file cannot be loaded. I have a third Mac which is still running 15.0 and things work perfectly on it. All the machines are mirrored for content files via Dropbox. My .bib file is in the same directory as my .tex file; texing is fine, it is only bibtex that complains.
Has anyone encountered this? TIA for any insights.
Here is hinted output.                 This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2024) Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003 The top-level auxiliary file: test1.aux The style file: plainnat.bst I couldn't open database file neal_bk.bib ---line 182 of file test1.aux : \bibdata{neal_bk :
Neal

Can you show what error message you get?

Please clarify whether you use MacTeX or TeXLive. (FWIW, I use MacOS 15.0.1. too, along with MacTeX2024, and I have not encountered this particular problem.)

I use texlive 2024 - setup works on older sequoia 15.0 and have not made systen changes. (Downloaded from tug via mactex.pkg and redone yesterday.) Here is the beginning of .aux file\relax
\citation{rsi:bk}
\citation{kkv:bk}
\citation{rsi:bk}
@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction and Historical Setting}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}

welcome! does bibtex return an error? if so, please paste the text of that error into your question. how are you compiling?

cloud folders can sometimes pose a problem. Just as a test: does it work if you copy the folder to a location which is not synced via dropbox?

(it looks like you have at least 3 different accounts. You can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact to merge your accounts. This way you would be able directly edit your question without having to wait until it goes through the review queue.)

thanks on accounts, will work on. On moving files off cloud, are all local but check by creating a new unsynched folder and same problem. But thanks
